# Can't create Xamarin Forms Picker custom rendere

Tags: ios, xamarin, custom-controls, xamarin.forms

Hi i easily created custom renderer for Forms Entry control, but when i tried to create one to Picker i get this error:

```
Error CS0115: `Punteam.iOS.PunteamPickerRederer.OnElementChanged(Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.Picker>)' is marked as an override but no suitable method found to override (CS0115) (Punteam.iOS)
```

this is my code on Forms project:

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Punteam
  {
  public class PunteamPicker : Picker
  {
 }
}
```

on IOS Project:

```
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform;
using Punteam;
using Punteam.iOS;
using UIKit;
using EventKitUI;

[assembly: ExportRenderer (typeof(PunteamPicker),      typeof(PunteamPickerRederer))]

namespace Punteam.iOS
{

public class PunteamPickerRederer : PunteamPicker
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged     (ElementChangedEventArgs<Picker> e)
{
/* base.OnElementChanged (e);

    this.Control.TextAlignment = MonoTouch.UIKit.UITextAlignment.Center;

    this.Control.TextColor = UIColor.White;

    this.Control.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
    this.Control.BorderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.RoundedRect;
    this.Layer.BorderWidth = 1.0f;
    this.Layer.CornerRadius = 4.0f;
    this.Layer.MasksToBounds = true;
    this.Layer.BorderColor = UIColor.White.CGColor;*/
   }
 }
}
```

Any body know's Why i get this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class PunteamPickerRederer : PunteamPicker
```

should be

```
public class PunteamPickerRederer : PickerRenderer
```